# How to view all issues of a github organization

Tags: github, github-issues

[This GitHub organization](https://github.com/i2mint) has (so far) 27 repositories in it. I'd like to be able to view them all at once instead of having to go, one by one, to each individual repository to see it's issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GitHub provides advanced search. For your case, if you want to lookup all the details in one place for the particular `i2mint` organization ,
Go to the [GitHub advanced search link](https://github.com/search/advanced) --> Enter `i2mint` in the `From these owners` field(it is usually the first field under section `Advanced Options`) --> You can provide other filters too if you like to --> Hit Search --> A page will show up with all data grouped by categories in left pane. The one of interest to you in this case is the `Issues`.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/search?o=desc&q=org%3Ai2mint&s=created&type=Issues

This url searches for issues from **i2mint** and sorts by **newest**. This is the breakdown of the parameters

- **q=org%3Ai2mint**: query is org:i2mint (search bar in top left corner)
- **o=desc**: Order descending (sort by at top right corner)
- **s=created**: Order by created (sort by at top right corner)
- **type=Issues**: Issue tab on the LHS (not repo, user or commit)

And all these can be adjusted from the UI.